# c# oracle max sort

Tags: c#, sql, oracle

please i need help guys i am trying to select some date from a table through c# connection for a oracle server and i want to get only the line with the max last_update_date my code

```
ocom.commandtext("@Select status,last_update_Date,trans_number
from pas.transaction
where last_update_Date in(select(last_update_Date) 
           from pas.transaction  
           where msisdn in("+mdc_line_M+") );
```

but it return nothing can anyone help as i am trying from 2 days ago

Comment: ocom.commandtext("@Select status,last_update_Date,trans_number from pas.transaction where last_update_Date in(select(last_update_Date) from pas.transaction where msisdn in("+mdc_line_M+") );

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use max(last_update_Date)

```
ocom.commandtext("@Select status,last_update_Date,trans_number
from pas.transaction
where last_update_Date in (
        select max(last_update_Date) 
       from pas.transaction  
       where msisdn in("+mdc_line_M+") 
);"
```

Comment: also fail please anyone help

Comment: what mean .."also fail" .. you have an error ?  .. or you obtain wrong .. result ..? update your question with a proper set of example data for a correct evaluation .

Comment: now i have an error and nothing come back and the error in line 130 which where last_update_Date in (     select max(last_update_Date) from pas.transaction  where msisdn in("+mdc_line_M+") );"

Comment: thank you solved all what i did i restarted visual studio and rebuild the program with your code and it's done thank you so much i think it was an internal error from visual studio  :D

Comment: Ok ... visual studio sometimes creates such problems .. good work

Comment: if you help me more now if i inserted more than msisdn i get just 1 record for the msisdn with the nearest update date can you help me to get all msisdn  records with the last update date :D ?

Comment: if you have more the one id  be sure you have properly formatted the string mdc_line_M  ... if id is a number then the result should be 1,2,3,4 if a string  '1','2','3','4'